# How to config routes in Spring Cloud Zuul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reload, netflix-zuul

In Spring Cloud Zuul server we can define all routes which need be redirected via "application.properties".

**For example:**

```
zuul.routes.resource.path=/api/**
zuul.routes.resource.url=http://api.com:9025
```

Once the fat jar is created the "application.properties" is encapsulated into jar, and it's not possible to edit and reload the rules inside the file.

Is there any to inform Zuul about the routes in an external file, and at the same time reload them without stopping the server?

Comment: After a while looking for a solution,  I found out that I can create a application properties for the zuul application inside config server,  for example zuul. properties and in there set all routes. That is important to mention the config client name in bootstrap.properties must have the same name that the application properties in config server.

Comment: can we load the `zuul.routes.resource.url` values from database instead..

Comment: Yes, we can.. But it's complicated. This pattern is called Service Discovery. Service Discovery enables you to change the service without stopping the gateway server (among other benefits). Spring supports Eureka, Consul, or Zookeper for Service Discovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...a bit late to the party, but...

You can do all that you want with the ConfigServer!

1. Create an application.yml for config that is common across ALL applications
2. Create profile specific application-mycommonprofile.yml. As 1. but for the 'mycommonprofile' profile.
3. Create an appX.yml for each application that is specific to that application.
4. Create profile specific appX-myprofile.yml. As 3. but for the 'myprofile' profile.

All of these files are optional and are not dependent on any others. You can have an application-mycommonprofile.yml without an application.yml for example.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can use spring cloud config for that.

Spring Cloud Config provides server and client-side support for externalized configuration in a distributed system. With the Config Server you have a central place to manage external properties for applications across all environments

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_client

Comment: The only inconvenient is Cloud Config Server shares those properties with all projects connected to it, keeping in mind the 'routes' properties are exclusively for Zuul server and at the same time I will have unnecessary properties for other projects. That's the matter!

Comment: Is there any way to inform Zuul server about how to reload the rules?

Comment: As far as I know the Config Server just share properties to the relative application. In my config server I have app1.yml, app2.yml, each app get your own properties. About the second question I don't' know if it's possible.

Comment: By now,  I  only have one application.properties for all applications. Do know if we can read the default application and the one for the specific application properties as you said?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution, but you can resolve it using profiles, you create the default application.yml, and one for each app like application-app1.yml,  application-app2.yml. I use it to to organize dev and production  environments.

Comment: For example,  if I have a common datasource which will be used by many applications I set all info about it in application.properties, this I do not need to repeat in all app1.yml, app2.yml.  That's why i would like to have one common prop and one specific.

Comment: sure. you can use profiles for it. when you start the application you pass the specific profile like that: java -jar app1.jar --spring.profiles.active=app1

Answer (score 0):

Another late-to-the-party answer, but another way is to use a profile config file, which lives in the filesystem, outside the fatjar.

If the configuration name of your Zuul proxy is 'zuul' and your normal config file is 'zuul.properties' or 'zuul.yaml', then it looks for a profile-specific config file in 'zuul-.properties' or 'zuul-.yaml'.
If you do not specify a profile, then the profile named 'default' is active.

So you can load properties from an external file name 'zuul-default.properties' or 'zuul-default.yaml' (or 'zuul-default.yml', if you use a 3-letter filename extension).
This will then be loaded when no other profile is specified.